# mastodon timeline API access returns empty?

Tags: mastodon

I want to get mastodon timeline posts from their API for
https://mastodon.social/@Exam5 (you can see there are 2 posts there), the API URL I used is:  https://mastodon.social/api/v1/timelines/tag/Exam5?limit=2, it returns an empty array. I tested some other hashtag name, I can get the post list array.

so I think there must be something I need to setup/configure in the account, which I have access, but not sure where or what to configure.

Please help. I am new to mastodon. thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the hashtag work, and here is the work around:
do a lookup and get the user id from:
https://mastodon.social/api/v1/accounts/lookup?acct=exam5
and use https://mastodon.social/api/v1/accounts/110684993683362177/statuses?limit=2 to the posts.